# Get collections with simple and grouped products with all activate

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get a collection of products between simple products and grouped products but the grouped products need have all those associated products active.

Any idea?.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
      $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
      foreach ($products as $product) {
             $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);    
             foreach ($associatedProducts as $aspro) {
                   echo "<pre>";print_r($aspro->getData());
             }
      }
?>
```